# Is there a way to implement some sort of search with PyGridTableBase?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Basically I want my grid to scroll to a (the first, the next) row containing what I have been searching for.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to make it scroll programmatically. You should try asking on the wxPython mailing list / Google Group though. A lot of good programmers are over there and they might know of a way.

Comment: That was a good hint, thanks Mike. Got a working solution there.

Answer (score 0):

My question has been answered in the Google Group wxPython-users, see here:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/wxpython-users/Tm-EVR2DxMA/discussion

grid.MakeCellVisible(row, col) does the trick, after you have analyzed your data and determined row and col you want to scroll to.